# How to do archiving in a Winforms C# Project with MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have a C# Winforms Project with MySQL as the backend. I'm wondering how to do archiving on my records. Is it done by inserting records from the active table to an archive table and deleting the records on the active table on the same database? or Is it done by inserting records from the active table in an active database to a clone table on an archive database and deleting the records on the active table? I'm just starting to learn this stuff, so I need assistance if someone could explain or at least give some examples.

Comment: By "archiving", do you mean "versioning"? If so, there are many ways to accomplish the goal. It really depends on what you plan on doing with the data later that should dictate a design pattern ...

Comment: @matigo, what i mean by archiving is that i wanted to archive inactive records to store it for retention purposes.